# Django 1054, "Unknown column 'emp_id' in 'field list"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-users, serialization

I am trying to add related field `emp_id` using **django admin username field**.

**emp_id:** was presented in **Employee** Table common name between Django admin and table Employee is `username`

i am using **DRF - SerializerMethodField** but still it says above error..

how do i solve this?

here is my model serializers,

**model,**

```
emp_id = models.ForeignKey(Employee, db_column='emp_id', null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

**serializer,**

```
emp_id = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name=None)
```

Comment: Please add your model class and serializer class structure.

Comment: updated my question check it now

Comment: Why are you using SerializerMethodField here? If your serializer is ModelSerializer or serializers.Serializer then it will come automatically but if it is of SerializerMethodField as in your case then create a method for this.

Answer (score 2):

here how I solved it using **SerializerMethodField**,

```
emp_id = serializers.SerializerMethodField('emp_id_from_nickname')
```

here, **emp_id_from_nickname** is the method, which helps to add value into my field.

```
def emp_id_from_nickname(self, model_obj):
   get_id = Employee.objects.get(usename=model_obj.username).emp_id
   return get_id

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'emp_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your serializer field to,

```
emp_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Employee.objects.all())
```

Comment: i am getting this error (1054, \"Unknown column 'auth_user.emp_id' in 'field list'\")"

Comment: thanks for your response. but i solved it using SerializerMethodField alone